# How to find Cordinates of document.DocumentElement.Client

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am able to get the width and height of a browser page using document.documentElement.clientWidth and document.documentElement.clientHeight.

Now, I want to know the top left and top right cordinates of the client viewport. Are there any scripts to find this?

[image]

I need to find (X,Y) and b - Any scripts for this?

Note - (m,n) and (X,Y) are with respect to the main Window Screen.

Comment: `topLeft` will be `(0, 0)` and `topRight` will be `(clientWidth, 0)` right ?

Comment: What i need is (X,Y) and b.. will i be able to achieve this?

Comment: Inner container is the `inner-div` of the `parent-div` ?

Comment: [__Element.getBoundingClientRect()__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) may help!

Comment: What would the "element" be for an entire browser page? And, the bounding rect will have (0,0) for the top-left. What i need is the cordinate with respect to the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

To get the client area position relative to the window:

```
var client_left = (window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth) / 2;
var client_top = (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight - client_left);
```

And to get the absolute position:

```
var x = window.screenLeft + client_left;
var y = window.screenTop + client_top;
```

Comment: I would like to know why is (window.outerWidth-window.innerWidth) divided by "2".

Comment: The client area left position is the width of the left border ("b" on your blueprint). Since there is two borders, we need to divide by two.

Comment: I have another question.. when the window is maximized, client_left is supposed to be "0", but it is "8". Any specific reason for this?

Comment: The client_left is 8 because the border is still there. When the window is maximized, the position of the window is [-8, -8].